# Slow mysql update with sum

Tags: mysql

I have query like this

```
UPDATE linksupload as lu SET lu.progress = (SELECT SUM(l.submitted)
           FROM links l
            WHERE l.upload_id = lu.id)
```

It takes 10 sec to execute. linksupload contains 10 rows, links contains 700k rows.

Query:

```
 UPDATE linksupload as lu SET lu.progress = (SELECT count(*)
               FROM links l
                WHERE l.upload_id = lu.id)
```

takes 0,0003 sek to execute. Also select with sum with group by from first query is fast. upload_id and id are indexes. Why first query takes so long time to execute? How to speed it up?

Comment: Have a look at the query plan by preceding the query with EXPLAIN - this will show how the query will be performed and which indexes if any will be used

Comment: It's 5.5 explain doesn't work

Comment: @john93230 I made this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/039261/1/3 hoping to show that update with join would perform faster but they're both pretty fast (800 ms vs 700 ms). I couldn't create 700K records because generating the data times out fiddle and the fiddle stops. This fiddle might help someone else answer the question or if you can reproduce it inside the fiddle we can try to fix it. Or try to update with join and see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks - join performs 10x times faster

Answer (score 0):

Indexes allow the database application to find data fast; without reading the whole table.

second query should be just count so it is not reading table. But first query should be sum of submitted column.So it is reading table.

First query should be slow.

Comment: So why SELECT SUM(l.submitted) FROM links l group by l.upload_id is fast?

Comment: No it is also slow. It must be all table to read not useful indexes key

Comment: I takes 0.0003 sec to execute as I said so in my opinion this is fast - of course first execute without cache